# Slow GPU comparison in Cupy

Tags: python, numpy, gpu, cupy

I want to test using cupy whether a float is positive, e.g.:

```py
import cupy as cp

u = cp.array(1.3)
u < 2.
>>> array(True)
```

My problem is that this operation is extremely slow:
`%timeit u < 2.` gives 26 micro seconds on my computer. It is orders of magnitude greater than what I get in CPU. I suspect it is because u has to be cast on the CPU...

I'm trying to find a faster way to do this operation.

Thanks !

**Edit for clarification**

My code is something like:

```py
import cupy as cp
n = 100000
X = cp.random.randn(n)  # can be greater
for _ in range(100):  # There may be more iterations
    result = X.dot(X)
    if result < 1.2:
        break
```

And it seems like the bottleneck of this code (for this `n`) is the evaluation of `result < 1.2`. It is still much faster than on CPU since the `dot` costs way less.

Comment: result will have the same value in every cycle of the loop; and likely will always be false. Is this intended behavior?

Comment: It is just an example to have the correct orders of magnitude, the actual code actually does something more meaningful.

Answer (score 9):

Running a single operation on the GPU is always a bad idea. To get performance gains out of your GPU, you need to realize a good 'compute intensity'; that is, the amount of computation performed relative to movement of memory; either from global ram to gpu mem, or from gpu mem into the cores themselves. If you dont have at least a few hunderd flops per byte of compute intensity, you can safely forget about realizing any speedup on the gpu. That said your problem may lend itself to gpu acceleration, but you certainly cannot benchmark statements like this in isolation in any meaningful way.

But even if your algorithm consists of chaining a number of such simple low-compute intensity operations on the gpu, you still will be disappointed by the speedup. Your bottleneck will be your gpu memory bandwidth; which really isnt that great compared to cpu memory bandwidth as it may look on paper. Unless you will be writing your own compute-intense kernels, or have plans for running some big ffts or such using cupy, dont think that it will give you any silver-bullet speedups by just porting your numpy code.

Comment: My code looks like the following: `X = cp.random.randn(int(1e5)); result = X.dot(X); if result < 1.: print('success')`. For this process, the bottleneck is actually the `if`part which is really frustrating. I'm wondering how to get around this.

Comment: The amount of work implied here is definitely not worth bothering the gpu for. The overhead of calling the kernel is going to far exceed the time to run this on the cpu

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have tested it, the code I have using GPU is much faster than using CPU. But the bottleneck in GPU is the comparison of a single float, which is frustrating. I have edited my original post with an example.

Comment: You also added another zero to the size of the array, which indeed puts it (marginally) in potential gpu acceleration territory. But you probably did not benchmark what you think you did. I imagine dot returns immediately; and only the implied copy back to the cpu by the if statement triggers a blocking call to wait for the gpu to return something.

Comment: I'm sorry, I try to give a minimal example which clearly highlights my problem. It is simple: my code in GPU is MUCH faster than my code without GPU. However, in GPU, the bottleneck is the `if` statement. No, the dots do not return immediately, I double checked it.

Comment: The call to dot would not return 'immediately' of course; the overhead of making a gpu call simply is quite substantial by itself. But does the documentation specify if it is a blocking or non blocking call? Cant find it quickly myself. Usually in gpu scripting youd pass these operations to the default stream in a non-blocking manner. Any easy way to get a definite answer is to play with the array size by a few orders of magnitude. If dot is nonblocking this should not matter for your timings of dot; but will matter for your 'timing of if'.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I have tried and changing the size of X does change the timing of the `dot` and not of the `if`, indicating that it is a blocking call if I get it right.

Comment: Then the only thing left to consider is the 'data transfer' back to the cpu; or rather the overhead thereof, because its a single element array. Try uploading a single element to the gpu; that should take about the same time as copying one back. If it takes any longer than that, id say file a bugreport with cupy.

Comment: `print`? is that even something on a GPU?

Answer (score 0):

This may be because, when using CUDA, the array must be copied to the GPU before processing. Therefore, if your array has only one element, it can be slower in GPU than in CPU. You should try a larger array and see if this keeps happening

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is your just leveraging one GPU device. Consider using say 100 to do all the for computations in parallel (although in the case of your simple example code it would only need doing once). https://docs-cupy.chainer.org/en/stable/tutorial/basic.html

Also there is a cupy greater function you could use to do the comparison in the GPU

Also the first time the dot gets called the kernel function will need to be compiled for the GPU which will take significantly longer than subsequent calls.